# How to retrieved data and store it in dynamic form according to the number of rows in php

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

I have a dynamic form wherein the user can add siblings in one form
[image]

When the user click that button. The system will add another row of **Name of Siblings**, **Date of Birth**, **Age** and **Education**.

[image]

Now, the information of Siblings are stored in my dabatabe and the name of the table is **siblings**

My question is how to retrieved that data and store it in dynamic form according to the number of rows This is my code:

```
$querySiblings = "SELECT * FROM siblings WHERE stud_inven_id = '$id'";
$resultSib = mysqli_query($connections, $querySiblings);
confirm_query($resultSib);

$check_row = mysqli_num_rows($resultSib);
if($check_row > 0){
  $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSib);

  //retrieve the dynamic form here...

}
```

And my dynamic form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>Name of Sibling/s according to birth order including you:</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name of Siblings</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_name[]" id="s_name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Date of Birth<span id="check"></span></label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="s_dob[]" id="s_dob" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Age<span id="check"></span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_age[]" id="s_age">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Education<span id="check"></span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_educ[]" id="s_educ">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <a href="#" id="addSiblings" class="btn btn-primary sib" >
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-md fa-user-plus"></i>
</a>
```

I'm doing the **UPDATE** user information. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: You should never put variables directly into a query. This leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. Instead, bind the variables. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Comment: Is this only for display of existing sibling data into this form? Or is there going to be an additional form on top (or bottom) to be used to also add new siblings as well?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. @Mike

Comment: Only display the existing data into my database @dmotors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to use a while loop.

```
$querySiblings = "SELECT * FROM siblings WHERE stud_inven_id = '$id'";
$resultSib = mysqli_query($connections, $querySiblings);
confirm_query($resultSib);

while(($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSib)) != null){
  // Your form with $fetch['sib_id'], $fetch['stud_inven_id'], etc...
  echo <<<EOF

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>Name of Sibling/s according to birth order including you:</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name of Siblings</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_name[]" id="s_name" value="$fetch[name]">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Date of Birth<span id="check"></span></label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="s_dob[]" id="s_dob" value="$fetch[dob]">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Age<span id="check"></span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_age[]" id="s_age" value="$fetch[age]">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Education<span id="check"></span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_educ[]" id="s_educ" value="$fetch[education]">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <a href="#" id="addSiblings" class="btn btn-primary sib" >
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-md fa-user-plus"></i>
</a>

EOF;
}
```

Be careful to don't add space or any other char before the last "EOF;"

I hope it was what you wanted.

Comment: What is **EOF** can do?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed from your text it said "according by birth order" so I added an extra ORDER BY to your query.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
<?php
    $querySiblings = "SELECT * FROM siblings WHERE stud_inven_id = '$id' ORDER BY dob ASC";
    $resultSib = mysqli_query($connections, $querySiblings);
    confirm_query($resultSib);

    $check_row = mysqli_num_rows($resultSib);
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Name of Siblings according to birth order including you:</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if ($check_row) { foreach (mysqli_fetch_all($resultSib, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $results) { ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name of Sibling</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $results['name'] ?>" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date of Birth<span id="check"></span></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<?= $results['dob'] ?>" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Age<span id="check"></span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $results['age'] ?>" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Education<span id="check"></span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $results['education'] ?>" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: @YadYoung Updated answer to only populate from the database now.